# How to call bootstrap-vue modals and toasts from vuex actions?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

Did anyone tried to use boostrap-vue in combination with vuex?
I'm having hard time calling modals and toast from vuex actions.

Obviously I can not use `this` from vuex store, therefore I can't use:

```
this.$bvModal.show('modalId');
```

I also tried calling modal like this

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.prototype.$bvModal.show('transaction');
```

But console gives me following warning:

**BootstrapVue warn]: '$bvModal' must be accessed from a Vue instance 'this' context**

Any idea how I can call modals and toasts from vuex actions directly?

Comment: If you're calling the action from a component you can pass the component Vue instance. `this.$store.dispatch('myAction', { vm: this })`, and you can then use that to access $bvModal in your action

Answer (score 7):

Try to call `this._vm.$bvModal.show('modalId');`.
[Reference](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399#issuecomment-449972993).

Comment: I've tried it, but it's not working. Just realized that I can use v-model on bootstrap modal so I'll just set state to true to show modal

Comment: Though i needed it for a nuxt app to show a toast, ._vm worked for me thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. The `this._vm.$bvModal` exists, but `.show('id'` does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I think a better approach is to prevent to deal with the UI from the Store. So, you can add a store property and watch for changes from your components.

In the following example, I added an array `toastMessages` in the `state` property and a `ADD_TOAST_MESSAGE` mutation to add some toastMessage. You can then commit an `ADD_TOAST_MESSAGE` mutation from another mutation or from an action.

Inside your Top-level component (`App.vue`), you can watch for your `toastMessages` state property changes and display the last item that was pushed.

**App.vue**

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  created() {
    this.$store.watch(
      state => state.toastMessages,
      toastMessages => {
        this.$bvToast.toast(this.toastMessages.slice(-1)[0]);
      }
    );
  }
}
</script>
```

**store.js**

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    toastMessages: []
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_TOAST_MESSAGE: (state, toastMessage) => (state.toastMessages = [...state.toastMessages, toastMessage]),
  },
  actions: {
    myActionThatDoSomething({commit}, params) {
      // Do something
      commit('ADD_TOAST_MESSAGE', "Something happened");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

found a solution here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399#issuecomment-491553564

```
import App from './App.vue';

const myStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        ...
    },
    actions: {
        myAction(ctx, data) {
           // here you can use this.$app to access to your vue application
              this.$app.$root.$bvToast.toast("toast context", {
                 title: "toast!"
              });
        }
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#my-div',
    render: h => h(App),
    store: myStore
});

myStore.$app = app; // <--- !!! this line adds $app to your store object
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @eroak idea, I have implemented this same thing for [vue-sweetalert2](https://github.com/avil13/vue-sweetalert2).

I have also created a store for my **Sweet Alert Toaster**, then I am watching a property called `ticks` that is updated whenever state of the toaster is updated.
I am using `ticks` as I only have one message in my state, and `ticks` just timestamp when action was triggered.

You can find whole demo here: https://github.com/Uraharadono/CallbackFromVuexAction

Answer (score -1):

Try to call this._vm.**$root**.$bvModal.show('modalId');